# Creating a virtual wifi switch!

Tags: linux, fedora

okie so i am not 100% new to fedora, i got some basic knowledge, and have it running as my secondary boot. recently i started getting issues with my acer aspire 5552 and the wifi adapter. usually it would connect to the network right away but now what happens is that when i boot into fedora right away my adapter is off. the command "rfkill list" tells me that my hardware is disabled. but once i boot to windows and then boot back to fedora everything works find.

so from this what i get is that my adapter disables itself, so my question is, is it possible to create a command that turns the adapter on, example:" like the FN+f4" in windows, if i try this in fedora it turns on/off flightmode.

thankyou

Comment: what i mean is the fn+f4 in windows is a shurt cut command for windows so is it possible to create the equivalent of this command for fedora, or mount windows partition and the specify a path to this command

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to. `rfkill` does that for you.

Or to be more precise, the `systemd-rfkill.service` does.

From the man page:

> systemd-rfkill.service is a service that restores the RF kill switch
>   state at early boot and saves it on each change. On disk, the RF kill
>   switch state is stored in /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/.

In other words, if you for example run:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

And enable `systemd-rfkill` with:

```
systemctl enable systemd-rfkill.service
```

Your system will automatically unblock all soft blocked devices upon starting the OS.

Comment: if im not wrong last time i tried the system detected it as a hard block (as if i turned the switch of my wifi adapter off, but the issue is i dont have one its done only via fn+f4)

Comment: Ah... well, if it is a hard (physical) block it is not controlled by `rfkill`.

Comment: exactly but as i said, i dont have a switch, that why im interested to see if there is a way to mount the winows partition and locate where the command to turn the wifi adapter on/off and give the path to it.                           plus for some reasons i do not have the systemd-rfkill in my systemctl options